# How to automatically unlock Windows at specific times

Tags: windows, uac, windows-task-scheduler, auto-login

I have a need to access the UI and it's not something that can be done with a locked computer with Task Scheduler.

My computer is a Windows 10 machine. My sign in type is PIN.

I tried to use anydesk but that didn't work either. I still want my computer to have a password. I would just like to have it automatically login at certain times. From there i will run a script and getting it locked back isn't a problem for me.

The task scheduler seems to require non-UI scripts, and the autologin doesn't allow password (`regedit` might be calling it wrong). I have thought of using autologon with a script and enabling and disabling it at certain times. It
didn't auto unlock unless i restarted and seemed janky if I did get it work.

For Task Scheduler these are my settings:
[image: General settings]
[image: Trigger settings]
[image: Action settings]
[image: Task on the list]

Comment: Task Scheduler can use Admin Credentials to unlock and run. Have the task lock the screen when done. Works in a great many cases. Why not for you?

Comment: is there a way i can include images? essentially it says task has not run yet  0x41303 . i had the time set for 2 minutes ago just to recheck this solution

Comment: You would probably have to add a batch file in the task for the images.

Comment: @John  i didnt mean like that i meant to the post i added the images to original post of the task creation and what it said after the set time passed. the only thing different is that my actual script run in background without the need to be turned on by task schedular so i just set it to a video to have it unlocked

Comment: I do not know how a video in a task can turn on an operating system.

Comment: @John the video is not important how can i turn it on

Comment: A batch file running inside Task Scheduler should be able to start Windows and run the Video

Comment: @John i added the batch file and it runs in the background but it doesnt auto unlock my computer and run batch in the foreground any clue why that would be this is my batch "timeout /t 10000 /nobreak > nul
PAUSE "

Comment: I kept looking but I do not see a reason at this point